# What does "fever in his eyes" mean?

Tags: meaning

A housekeeper says to Armanda about Vincent's behavoir:

> Housekeeper: I could see the **fever in his eyes** at first glance.

What does "fever in his eyes" mean?

Comment: She could see from the expression in his eyes that he (a) literally had a fever, or (b) was mentally disturbed (depending on context).

Comment: LOL. What is the context here? This could mean at least three different things.